# kafka startup error ubuntu class load failure

Tags: ubuntu, apache-kafka

I am getting following error after trying to start kafka. Although I can see the zookeeper service is started and listening to the right port specified in the server.properties and jre is installed

```
  > bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties 
    Error: Could not find or load main class config.server.properties
```

Comment: Can you provide your kafka downloaded binary package name? something like `kafka_2.10-0.10.0.0.tgz`

Comment: I had to download different kafka package. And error is gone now.

Answer (score 1):

I wrongly downloaded the source package and had the same problem. I've just downloaded the right package and it worked fine.